# How to recreate 3D "pixel art" characters

Tags: modeling

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFVzo2XOH4M) on youtube related to the movie Pixels from 2015 and I really want to replicate the style they used on Q*bert (The orange pixel/block guy).

How did they do the "pixel" texture on Q*bert's body?

Did they use particle systems or something else?

Do any of you know a way to replicate the style in blender that works with rigging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way to do it is to use the *Remesh* modifier / *Blocks* mode, here is what it gives with Suzan:

[image]

Comment: I love you man!